# Mojolicious Tests: How to get the input value using css-selectors

Tags: html, perl, css-selectors, mojolicious

I am writing a test for a Mojolicious Application, which sends some HTML form data and then checks, if they show up in the subsequent get request.

```
$t->post_ok('/intern/offer/edit'  => form  => {
      'angebotsdatum'    => '2014-02-22',
      'gastname'         => 'Hansi Hinterseer',
      'einmalkosten'     => '128.00',
      'tage'             => '9',
      'ankunft'          => '2014-01-01',
      'gesamtpreis'      => '764.00',
      'abfahrt'          => '2014-01-10',
      'tagespreis'       => '70.71',
      'apartments_id'    => 'HAG28',
      'id'               => '1',
      'aufenthaltspreis' => '636.39'
    }
)
->status_is(200)
->content_like( qr/Angbot bearbeiten/ )
;

$t->get_ok('/intern/offer/edit/1')
    ->status_is(200)
    ->text_like('html body h2' => qr/Intern - Angebote/ )
    ->text_like('html body h3' => qr/Angbot bearbeiten/ )
    ->text_is('html body form div#adatum label' => 'Angebotsdatum:' )
    ->text_is('html body form div#adatum input#angebotsdatum value'  => '2014-02-22' )
;
```

Unfortunately the last test for the value of the input element fails, since the returned value is always empty. The test for the form-**label** (here 'Angebotsdatum:') succeeds.

How can I select and get back the input-elements **value** from a HTML-form?

The HTML-code of the form is:

```
<div id="adatum">
    <label>Angebotsdatum:</label>
    <input type="text" name="angebotsdatum" value="2014-02-22" id="angebotsdatum">
</div>
```

And this is the test-output:

```
#   Failed test 'exact match for selector "html body form div\#adatum input[name=angebotsdatum] value"'
#   at t/1210-workflow_booking.t line 80.
#          got: ''
#     expected: '2014-02-22'
```

So we can see clearly, that the CSS-selector **returns the empty value**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Test::Mojo](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/SRI/Mojolicious-5.28/lib/Test/Mojo.pm)

> The **text_is** - Checks text content of the CSS selectors first
>   matching HTML/XML element for exact match with **at** in Mojo::DOM.

The `at` method

> Find first element in DOM structure matching the CSS selector and
>   return it as a Mojo::DOM object or return undef if none could be
>   found. All selectors from "SELECTORS" in Mojo::DOM::CSS are supported.

And the

```
html body form div#adatum input#angebotsdatum value
                                             ^^^^^^ - this isn't valid
```

IMHO, isn't valid CSS selector.

You can try the next (shortened) selector:

```
div#adatum > input[value="2014-02-22"]
```

so find the element `<input>` what has an attribute equal to `2014-02-22`.

> E[foo="bar"]
>   An E element whose foo attribute value is exactly equal to bar.

More info [Mojo::DOM::CSS#SELECTORS](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::DOM::CSS#SELECTORS)

So, it is enough test the existence of the element exactly with the wanted value:

```
->element_exists('input[value="2014-02-22"]', '...');
```

*Ps: I'm not an very experienced Mojo developer, so ...*

Comment: Good eye, jm666.  I'm not a very experienced Mojo dev either, but that looks right.

Comment: It's a valid CSS selector, it just attempts to match elements in a way that doesn't make sense in valid HTML.

Comment: @BoltClock yeah, should be better said - isn't valid for the purpose and context as the OP wants..

Answer (score 1):

`input#angebotsdatum` means you are looking for an `<input>` element with an `id=angebotsdatum` attribute, but what you want to look for is a `name=angebotsdatum` attribute. So I think the last test should look something like

```
->text_is('html body form div#adatum input[name=angebotsdatum] value' => ...)
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer! Unfortunately that does not solve the problem. The input element has both an _id_ and a _name_ of `angebotsdatum`. I'll try to add the HTML-code above in my question.